# Circuit design of backup power with rechargeable battery

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging

I'd like to equip arduino uno with a backup battery. The goal is to send a SMS via SIM800L module in case mains power is interrupted. This is the schematics I found online. It is not 100% clear to me how it works.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fns7S0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am particularly interested in

- If additional circuit logic is needed to recharge battery when it is not being used? Or do you just connect 12V battery to 12V DC and be done?
- What type of rechargeable battery is needed in this case?
- Is it battery friendly to connect it to DC for long period?
- How can I detect with Arduino when voltage source was changed from adapter to battery?

In case both battery and adapter are operational, why is voltage sourced from the adapter and not the battery? I think resistor R1 is used to limit the current flow **to** the battery when mains power is on, but not **from** the battery. Why is this needed? I think diode D2 function is to provide a low resistance path for current to flow in case of power failure. Can you verify my thinking? I am looking forward to reading your answers.

Comment: If you found a schematic which does not say for what purpose it is, nobody else can guess either. It is not known which batteries should be used or how much capacity you even need, how fast battery must recharge and how long it must power your load, and what current your load takes. Detecting if mains adapter gives voltage or batteries is the easiest part. Resistor is needed to trickle charge battery, a 12V power supply is not a battery charger so a power supply would try to push as much as current it can into battery to try rising the battery voltage to 12V, but it just shuts down.

Comment: "If you found a schematic which does not say for what purpose it is, nobody else can guess either". The purpose is to supply backup power. Does it work and is production ready? That is why I am asking . The backup is for arduino uno. Unos draw 40mA in low power mode. I do not know how much amps is needed to send a text message, but expect not much more than the uno itself. Power outages are rare where I live. Once a month. Recharge time of 1 day is fine.

Comment: R1 will slowly charge the battery when power is plugged in. If this is the intention then you should know the fully charged voltage of your battery and make sure the DC supply  supplies that voltage (plus D1 forward voltage). And only lead-acid batteries can be charged this way, not lithium.

Answer (score 1):

Will this circuit work? Yes

Will it work reliably over longer periods of time? Maybe... It depends!

It will depend on your selection of components...

Lead Acid Batteries can take small charging currents over prolonged periods of time. Just remember to check the liquid level from time to time. NiCd are also quite resistant to this (but not available anymore). LiIon don't take very well to beeing overcharged.

But in any case, the input voltage has to be within more or less tight tolerances. A 12V lead acid battery has 14.4V when fully charged. NiCd and NiMH have around 1.2V per cell. LiIon have 4.1V to 4.2V per cell when fully charged.

So what kind of battery you want to use will have big influence on whyt kind of circuit will work.

In the circuit you found the Source with the higher voltage will "win" and supply the circuit. The diodes are there to make sure that the sources do not backfeed into each other. The resistor is there to slowly charge the battery when the power supply is on.

### Things to consider

- Current consumption

  - Diodes must be able to carry the current needed
  - the Power supply must be able to deliver the current needed by the load **plus** the charging current of the battery
- Deep discharge

  - Your circuit does not provide any protection against deep discharge of the battery. No battery chemistry I know of "likes" deep discharge. You will need a circuit to protect the battery or the lifetime will be severly limited
- Charging

  - The simplest way of charging is with constant voltage and current limiting. You need a way to precisely control the charging voltage to the required value
  - There is almost no limit on how fancy to get with charging circuit. It depends on Battery chemistry, how fast you want/need to charge, how long ypou want your batteries to live and how serious you take fire hazards

### Conclusion

the circuit above can work but will most probably not be very long lived

### Alternative solution

Look at super capacitors! Depending on how much current your circuit needs and how long you need to be able to bridge a blackout, super capacitors might be the right solution for you. They are much easier to handle and take repeated (deep) cycling extremely well.